# When merging two nameless vector, it becomes splitted and not be 1 column

Tags: r

In this data, I want to stack second data after one data. So I coded as below:

```
billboard.html <- read_html("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2018-01-03")

title <- as.vector(billboard.html %>% 
                     html_nodes('.chart-number-one__title') %>% 
                     html_text())
title <- rbind(title, as.vector(billboard.html %>% 
                                  html_nodes('.chart-list-item__title-text') %>% 
                                  html_text()))
title <- gsub("\n", "", title)

title
```

If It work as I thought, the result should be 100 row, 1 column dataset. But there is 2 row, 100 column dataset continuously. I totally couldn't understand this situation. Please help me.

Comment: You can try `rbind("a", c("b", "c", "d"))` and observe its output. This is what you do in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining vectors you should use `c()` and not `rbind()` (which is used to bind `data.frame`s vertically).

```
require(rvest)

billboard.html <- read_html("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/2018-01-03")

title <- as.vector(billboard.html %>% 
                     html_nodes('.chart-number-one__title') %>% 
                     html_text())

title <- c(title, as.vector(billboard.html %>% 
                                  html_nodes('.chart-list-item__title-text') %>% 
                                  html_text()))
title <- gsub("\n", "", title)

title
```

Comment: Thanks. It is really helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help! and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)